# FJSTransitionController setup and use in View Controller not main app delegate

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set up Corey Floyd's FJSTransitionController. My app uses a main view controller to manage the main view navigation.

I also went through the source to fix it for ARC.

Followed instructions and in my main delegate .h I have in the usual spots:

```
FJTransitionController* mainTransitionController;

@property (nonatomic,retain) FJTransitionController* mainTransitionController;
```

delegate .m has the following

```
@synthesize mainTransitionController
```

And in the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
mainTransitionController=[[FJTransitionController alloc] init]; // do I need to instantise?
[self.window addSubview:mainTransitionController.view];

[mainTransitionController setViewControllerClass:[[mainViewController sendMissionsPanelViewController] class] forKey:@"missionView"];
```

The last line is complaining that there is no @interface for FJTransitionController?

Any help please.

Comment: There are multiple ways to set a view controller as you found, you can use just the class, of you can provide a fully instantiated view controller. It is hard to read from the question what your exact issue was, maybe you can reword?

Comment: I was pretty damm sure I set it up correct but ran out of time to debug it, I was concerned because even use the class route with my Custom classes didn't work. I ended solving it with a bit of trickier using the UINavigationController class. Thanks heaps, I just didn't have time to delve into it. It might of been setting it up for ARC. cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Ok tad brain dead today but a quick look at the header file revealed there is no setViewControllerClass so I just used the setViewController method.

```
[mainTransitionController setViewController:[mainViewController sendMissionsPanelViewController] forKey:@"missionView"];
```

Seems to be type safe. Yet to Test it thou!

Edit: That method setViewControllerClass is exposed in the header so it must be another issue.